# Conversion of JPEG with JSON coordinates into a GeoTIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, convert, jpg

I have a JSON file that contains 1000 sets of coordinates that relate to 1000 different/separate JPEGs.

How do I go about incorporating the coordinates into the JEPG to create the georeferenced JPEG, so that I can then go and convert to GeoTIFF?

Or is there a way that I can do this directly from just the JPEG and JSON coordinates alone?

Is there a programmatic solution/library for this in Python by chance?

Below is a sample of the JSON data:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000000" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.540445928999986 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.537699346969575 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000001" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.537699346969575 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.534952764939163 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000002" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.534952764939163 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.532206182908752 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000003" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.532206182908752 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.52945960087834 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000004" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.52945960087834 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.526713018847957 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe look into using gdal or rasterio.

Comment: Have you looked at creating "world files" from the coordinates - basically if you have foo.jpg and foo.jpgw is a text file specifying the corner coordinates, then you have a spatial JPG understood by most GIS. Search for the world file format and then use your programming of choice to create one for each jpg from the json. Hard to do any more without seeing the JSON format or knowing your skillset.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Are those points meant to be in the vicinity of Atlanta, GA? (specifically, close to the LM plant)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the points are really in Antarctica, I think you've got your longitude and latitude reversed. If so, and you reverse them so they are in longitude, latitude order, they appear to be in Atlanta GA

Assuming the multi-points represent the lower left and upper right coordinates of the images and that the images don't need to be warped, using python  you could read the point coordinates using [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) and use [`rasterio`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_bounds) to georeference the images from those coordinates.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.transform import from_bounds


gdf = gpd.read_file("coordinates.geojson")

for record in gdf.itertuples():
    # assuming file is {name}.jpg
    # open in r+ (update) mode so the updated transform gets saved to
    # {name}.jpg.aux.xml which is a GDAL PAM sidecar metadata file
    # that any software that uses GDAL (such as QGIS) understands 
    with rio.open(f"{record.name}.jpg", "r+") as ds:
        ds.transform = from_bounds(*record.geometry.bounds, height=ds.height, width=ds.width)
```

For example, given the following (reversed) geojson and a completely  ungeoreferenced screenshot clipped from OpenStreetMap called 000001.jpg, running the above code results in this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000001" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -84.5376993469696, 33.9342040635691 ], [ -84.5349527649392, 33.936482815 ] ] } }
]
}
```

[image]

And with the now georeferenced screenshot overlaid onto a different (Bing) basemap:

[image]